# Port forwarding with virtual machines

Tags: network-configuration, virtual-machine

I have configuration like:

Router [External IP: 91.111.91.111] -> PC [Nat IP: 192.168.1.20] -> Virtual Machine as a Gateway (Whonix - Tor) [Nat IP 10.0.2.15 + Internal Network 10.152.152.10] internal network is for next Virtual Machine -> Virtual Machine Workstation [NAT IP: 10.152.152.50] on this workstation I have installed NoIP DNS: test.noip.com which always shows IP of Tor exit node.

Now I want to forward port 9000 to that machine. So I set up port forwarding on router and on both Virtual Machines. But it doesn't work.

I lost something and not sure where I made mistake.

Comment: Even with it allowed by the hypervisor, the gateway config will be forcing the workstation to connect over Tor for everything outbound and dropping attempts to connect to it from outside. Poking holes through Whonix's carefully constructed isolation seems dangerous. *Why*?

Comment: That what I thought, thanks, I am testing RAT over Tor, just for fun and knowledge.

Comment: ah, a script kiddy. that explains the lack of understanding of basic networking.

Comment: ekhm, yeah sure dude, call it whatever you want if you feel better adding so usefully comment :)